# how to increment 1 value in email address for uniqueness in selenium webdriver

Tags: email, selenium

I am writing test script for signup page and i need to put email address on each time. Can someone help me how to increment by value 1 in the email address as i execute the script for example, test@test.com and next time value should be test1@test.com. I an try with time stamp but not successfully work.

```
public class GetCurrentTimeStamp 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
     java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
     System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:-

```
    int num = 1; // Put this stament outside the for loop or put it as global variable.
```

Now use below code :-

```
    num++;
    String email= "test"+ num + "@test.com";
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks to all, yes this is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Use java.util.Date class instead of Timestamp and format it like so.
`String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date()); 
 String email= "test"+ timestamp + "@test.com";`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to provide always unique email id, then you can use date with seconds as it keep changing also you can use

```
 System.currentTimeMillis()
```

which gives number always unique. so you can append/concatenate it to email, i hope you know it.

You can use below code to get date

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
 Date date = new Date();
 System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date)); //2016/04/19 16:05:48
```

depends of simple date format provide 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss' output will be displayed.

Thank You,
Murali